What's the intended or minimum time complexity of the Preferred IUPAC Name (PIN) algorithm?
For a school project, I've made a program which will convert the structural formula or SMILES input of a molecule to the systematic IUPAC name, for the set of molecules which could be asked on the Dutch chemistry high school exams (so no ring systems for example).
For this I could achieve a time complexity of $O(n^3)$, where n is the number of atoms in the molecule. The bottleneck of the algorithm was the selection of the principal chain. Because there are $O(n)$ starting points and $O(n)$ ending points for the principal chain, there are $O(n^2)$ paths to compare (a principal chain can't consist partly of a both a ring and not a ring, so there is at most one valid path between two points). However, if the first few  $O(1)$ criteria for the paths are the same (like maximum number of characteristic groups, maximum length, et cetera) the locants of the principal chain candidates must be compared. This comparison happens in $O(n)$ in the worst case. So taking the best out of all these $O(n^2)$ chains is $O(n^3)$.
It may be possible to reduce it to $O(n^2)$, as it’s unlikely (or impossible?) that $O(n^2)$ main chain bonds would all achieve maximum scores on the first few $O(1)$ criteria.
So my question is: what would be the minimum time complexity of the full PIN algorithm, also considering ring systems and all other rules? And when the PIN algorithm was designed, was this considered?
Edit:
Thanks for your responses!
Since I have already created a program for the basic nomenclature operations, I know about the algorithms for longest path in a tree and such.
You could indeed do a double DFS for a longest path, but the problem is the fact you need all longest paths so you can compare them. In the worst case (two binary trees attached to a single node), this is still $O(n^2)$ paths, so time complexity wise it's no better than just checking the path from every node to every other node.
As far as I know the nomenclature of ring systems is not based on the longest path but instead of the whole ring system with its bridges. Maybe this is intentional, if the nomenclature was based on the longest path it would indeed be a exponential time complexity which is of course horrible and should be avoided at all costs.
"I'd also guess IUPAC was more interested originally in a name leading to a unique structure than a unique name for a structure."
Yeah the IUPAC naming system has been around since 1958 but the system for a unique name for a structure (PINs) was only finished in 2013.
I asked this question on the chemistry stack exchange because to main questions are
a) What is the minimum time complexity for the whole of the PIN naming system?
Answering this question requires extensive knowledge of the whole of PIN naming, because minor details (like the lowest locants) in the rules can change the time complexity significantly, and knowing the rules for more complicated structures like ring systems is required. It's unlikely that a computer scientist has the time to study the 1162 pages of the 2013 rules to answer the question. I can ask part of the question, like if only the nomenclature for acyclic compounds is possible in anything better than $O(n^3)$, on the computer science stack exchange, but that wouldn't answer question a nor question b fully.
b) What's the intended time complexity of the PIN naming system? I think only people who were involved in the Preferred IUPAC Name project or people who have worked on naming algorithms for programs like ACD/ChemSketch or Lexichem TK can answer this question.
Since this is about a man-made system for nomenclature and his little to do with real world phenomena I don't think matter modelling is the right stack exchange.
For the nomenclature of acyclic compounds there may be a way to do it in $O(n)$, by using the double DFS method but changing the definition of 'longest' so it incomparates aspects like double bonds etc. But I'm unsure if this will work for the lowest set of locants rule.
Using a lookup table is very much not the point, you would still need an algorithm to create the name before adding them to the lookup table, and there are almost an infinite number of possible organic compounds.

With an interdisciplinary questions like this (need to know some chemistry and some computer science), you might have more luck at matter modeling or (if you explain the chemistry) at computer science.

Of course, for a limited set of molecules one could just calculate them all and then use a lookup table.

Agree that Computer Science or Computational Science might have thoughts on this if the question is carefully explained - there's probably overlap with the shortest path problem, but with a maximum instead of a minimum. Matter Modelling may also have somebody who knows something. It's an interesting question, I hope it doesn't fall between the gaps

This is possibly a computational geometry and/or graph theory question. Some data structures may allow you track the maximal path through the graph as you build it. I suspect this is both a well-understood and solved problem.

This answer is mainly about relevant aspects of graph theory and efficiency. Consider first the simple but common case where there are no rings and there is a unique longest chain. In graph theory, where the carbon/hetero atoms (I'll just say carbon for simplicity) are the vertices, and the bonds are the edges, a graph without rings ("cycles") is called a tree graph. So we need to find the longest chain ("path") in a tree, which can be done in $O(n)$.
As indicated here this can be done by two depth-first searches (DFS). Choose any carbon, and move along to one of the next carbons. Repeat until you can't go any further, recording where you have been. Back up, and at the previous carbon, take an unvisited edge and again move down the branches until you again come to a dead end. Repeat this process until all the carbons have been visited. Take the carbon the furthest away from your starting carbon; this is one end of the longest chain.
Now use this carbon as a starting point and do another depth-first search; the carbon furthest away is the other end of the longest chain. As you do this one you could collect information about the types of atoms (for priority rules) and where the branch points are. Depth-first search is $O(\mathrm{\# edges} + \mathrm{\# vertices})$ and since the number of edges is one fewer than the number of edges for a tree this is $O(n)$. So you do not need to investigate paths between all possible terminal carbons.
At this point, you know which way along the chain the numbering will go. For each branch point, you could do a DFS to find out about the side chains (or Dijkstra's algorithm, which finds the shortest paths from one vertex to all of the others (omitting those on the main chain)). Possibly you could have collected enough information in the two early DFS to bypass this step, but I didn't think much about this.
For cases with multiple chains of the same longest length, you have a more difficult problem. However, this is helped by the fact that for a tree all the longest paths go through the center. So having found the longest chain, find its center. If the chain has an odd number of carbons, the center will be on an atom. Do a DFS from that atom and then assemble all the chains from the half-chains found. For an even number of carbons, the center is an edge, but a DFS from one of the two atoms on the ends of the center bond is sufficient to assemble the longest chains. So the searching part is still $O(n)$, but assembling the chains will depend on the number of longest chains there are. As you say, the worst case can have many longest chains, as would occur for a dendrimer.
With rings, the rules are complicated, and finding the cycles is also complicated. It is perhaps worth pointing out that finding the longest path in an arbitrary graph is very difficult: it can't be done in $O(n^\alpha)$ time where $\alpha$ is a constant; roughly speaking the time is exponential in $n$. But that is for a path that might include a ring or part of one, so perhaps isn't relevant in the chemical setting.
I don't know much about the history of IUPAC PIN, much less its time complexity. I'd guess checking the various special rules, especially for ring systems, could take more time than the basic algorithms. I'd also guess IUPAC was more interested originally in a name leading to a unique structure than a unique name for a structure. InCI was developed by them for the latter purpose in a computing environment, much later than the IUPAC notation rules (though they keep changing). Despite that, SMILES seems to be more widely used.
